# How can i apply datepicker() to every table character in django template?

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, datepicker

My current read out only displays the datapicker on the first line ran even though it is in the for loop my jquery is not strong, but i believe that is where my issue is.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()
    $( "#format" ).change(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

This is just the html of my code maybe i need to add a class to this, but that should not matter if jquery runs the code based on the id.

```
                <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>   Check All</th>
                    <th>Rootname </th>
                    <td>Urls</td>
                    <th>custs </th>
                    <th> jvmms </th>
                    <th>x64 </th>
                    <th>currentplatform </th>
                    <th> currentjdk </th>
                    <th>currenttomcat </th>
                    <th>Time </th>
                    <th>Date </th>
                </tr>
                    {% for status in root %}
                <tr>
                <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case"></td>
                    <td>{{ status.rootname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ status.urls }}</td>
                    <td>{{ status.custs }}</td>
                    <td> {{ status.jvmms }}</td>
                    <td>{{ status.x64 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ status.currentplatform }}</td>
                    <td> {{ status.currentjdk }}</td>
                    <td>{{ status.currenttomcat }}</td>
                    <td><p> <input type="text" class="pick" id="datepicker" size="25" /></p></td>
                            <td>
                <input type="text" value="12:00" size="3" />
                <select name="ampm">
                    <option value="am">AM</option>
                    <option value="pm">PM</option>
                </select></td>


                </tr>

                    {% endfor %}

            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the jquery code to the class not the element id:

```
$(".pick").datepicker();
$("#format").change(function() {
      $(".pick").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
});
```

The difference between the id and class is that a class can be used repeatedly on a page but id can be used only once. So if you attach any function to the id selector, it will be used only once.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me get my solution closer to being solved, but the output only gets displayed on the 1 table row instead of each individual table row

Answer (score 0):

Matino was correct in her statement about the class of course, but using django you just have to add a forloop.counter inside the html as well.

```
**$(".pick").datepicker();
$("#format").change(function() {
  $(".pick").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", $(this).val());
    });**

<td> <p class= "selector"> <input type="text" class="pick" id="datepick **{{forloop.counter}}**" size="25"  /> </p> </td>
                        <td>
```